# Is there a way to create an email server without a third party?

Tags: python, mailer

Is there way make my windows pc as Mail server to senD Emails to members from Django of python code?
And that without external SMTP mailer such as Google or Yahoo.

For example when am using Python to sent mail I get this error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Many mail servers will not accept mail directly from residential IPs, as a spam-blocking measure.

Comment: Many residential ISPs block the ports necessary to operate a mailserver (for exactly the same reason).